# How To Handle Two JSON Responses in C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, jwt

I'm coding in C# for Xamarin Forms and using JWTAuth to authenticate a username and password on Wordpress.

However I'm receiving two JSON responses that doesn't seem to populate the variables.

JSON Response 1:

```
{"success":false,"statusCode":403,"code":"invalid_username","message":"Unknown username. Check again or try your email address.","data":[]}
```

JSON Response 2:

```
{"success":true,"statusCode":200,"code":"jwt_auth_valid_credential","message":"Credential is valid","data":{"token":"xxxxx","id":xxxx,"email":"xxxxx","nicename":"xxxx","firstName":"xxxx","lastName":"xxxx","displayName":"xxxx"}}
```

You'll notice that the second response, if the user is validated, it fills extra details in the data key values.

I tried deserialising these two responses into one class but it doesn't seem to populate the variables if a user has successfully been validated which is strange.

Here's my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Running Authentication...");

string JWTAPI = "https://xxxx/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token";

var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = JWTAPI;

var jsonContent = "{ \"username\": \"" + EntryLoginUsername + "\", \"password\": \"" + EntryLoginPassword + "\"}";

StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response_status = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

var response_result = await response_status.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

JWTJSONResponse = response_result;

Console.WriteLine(JWTJSONResponse);

Root JWTResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JWTJSONResponse);

Console.WriteLine("Result: " + JWTResults.success);

            if (JWTResults.success.ToString() == "True")    
            {
                ResultTextHeader.Text = "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!";
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code: " + JWTResults.statusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Code: " + JWTResults.code);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + JWTResults.message);
            }
            else
            {
                ResultTextHeader.Text = "Unsuccessful login. Please try again.";
            }
```

And my classes:

```
public class Data
        {
            public string token { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string nicename { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string displayName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            // JWT
            public bool success { get; set; }
            public int statusCode { get; set; }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public List<object> data { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in JSON Response 1, `data` is an empty **array**. In JSON Response 2 `data` is a non empty **object**.

Your class `Root` has a property `data` which is of type `List<object>`. This can only deal with an array. To make it work, change `Root.data` to be of type `Data` as in:

```cs
public class Root
{
    // JWT
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if you have access to it, change the JSON Response 1 to be `{ <omitted code>, data: null }` instead of `{ <omitted code>, data: [] }`. It doesn't make a lot of sense for it to be an array in the "no data" case and an object in the "with data" case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your rest call to validate user credentials will send 403 when user is not authorized. I think you are not setting class object properly for deserialising.
Try with below where I have set `Data` class in `Root` class

Firstly you need class to deserialize data and does not look correct,

```
   public class Data
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string nicename { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        // JWT
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public int statusCode { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

Root JWTResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(JWTJSONResponse);
```

Also checking for response like this is not valid,

```
if (JWTResults.success.ToString() == "True")
```

Instead you should always check the response code of API **(200/403/401)**
You should get that in,

```
    var response_status = await client.PostAsync(uri, content)
    if (response_status.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
       //Return error ??
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohan, you're right it was the public Data data part that needed to be changed. It's working now. I'll also use your code to validate the response code returned, very useful.

Comment: @Khoa if this works, could you also mark this as accepted answer. This helps to idnetify someone if it was working or not :)